# Printing a part from two materials

Tags: prusa-i3

I am trying to print a large part from PolyPro but can't get it to stop warping when I remove it. It also doesn't stick well. I have tried playing with printing speeds, temps, extrusion % etc. Even tried putting packing tape on the bed (which helped it stick but didn't prevent the warping).

I thought I might try printing a base layer (2 mm) of PLA, the print the rest of the the part in PP right on top of it. The PLA hopefully will stick and keep the walls of the part straight. My question is how to do this. Is it as easy as cutting off the bottom 2 mm of the part and telling the design software that the part rests 2 mm above the bed, then tell Cura not to print a support?

Comment: Why not only pause your print after 2mm, change the filament and resume your print to be completed?

Comment: If your part warps *after* you remove it, then it might be a part design problem. Please attach links to the photos which show how it warps.

Also, your method with 2mm offset will result in a mid-air first layer, which never ends well. Follow Fernando's advice here.

Answer (score 2):

You could just let it print the 2mm you want for the base, then pause the print and change the filament to PP and then resuming the print after you change the filament.

Comment: If PP prints at a different temperature than PLA, you would want to adjust the temperature while you are changing the filament.